# Example of 1D ConvNet filter

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, deep-learning, convolution, cnn

I understand `Conv2D` filters. I think I understand `Conv1D` filters as well but have not seen any examples of the filters like what we have in 2D filters, e.g. `Sobel` as shown in the following image. Are there any standard one dimensional filters?

**Sobel 2D Filter example**

[image: Sobel Filter]

Answer (score 1):

Images are two dimensional signals. The use of `Conv1D` is for one dimensional signals like voice and sound. CNNs are good for these signals too because of taking care of local input patterns. Definitely there are standard one dimensional filters which are most used in signal processing like *high pass filters* and *low pass filters* which are so much popular. In order to show you an example take a look at the following figure which illustrates the convolution of two signals:

[image]